# How to express the statement when a user have the chance to choose either action1 or action2 in sequence diagram uml

Tags: uml

I want to know how to express the fact that the user has the chance to choose between action1 or action2 in sequence diagram UML : which means he can either do action1 or action2.
Please help me if you know the answer and Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: use a combined fragment 'alt'

Comment: @bruno, you should make it an answer rather than putting it in the comment. Add an example diagram and you can be sure to have my upvote.

Comment: @Ister no need, there are already answers on S.O. so I propose to close for duplicate